# Unpack multiple floats from input()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is what I need:
The user to input 4 comma separated float values which I will use to create my my rectangle class.

Here is my current approach:

1)Get user input with input()

2) Split() the input into lists

3)Unpack it into variables

4)Turn those variables (which are strings) into floats

At this point I get an error because the commas have not been separated from the string values, so trying to convert into float gives a type error. I could get around this by making a for each loop go through every value individually and format it, but this is unnecessarily complex. My question is, how can I do this in a much cleaner, simpler way?

```
def main():
    
    x1,y1,width1,height1 = input("Enter x1, y1, width1, height1: ").split()
    
    x1,y1,width1,height1 = float(x1),float(y1),float(width1),float(height1)
    
    r1 = Rectangle2D(x1,y1,width1,height1)

    x2,y2,width2,height2 = input("Enter x2, y2, width2, height2: ").split()
    x2,y2,width2,height2 = float(x2),float(y2),float(width2),float(height2)
    r2 = Rectangle2D(x2,y2,width2,height2)
    
class Rectangle2D:

    def __init__(self, x = 0.0, y = 0.0, width = 0.0, height = 0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
```

Sample run:

```
Enter x1, y1, width1, height1: 9, 1.3, 10, 35.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lisa Dueker\Desktop\comp sci\week 9\HW\8.19.py", line 127, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Lisa Dueker\Desktop\comp sci\week 9\HW\8.19.py", line 4, in main
    x1,y1,width1,height1 = float(x1),float(y1),float(width1),float(height1)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '9,'
```

Comment: `split()` splits on whitespace. If you want to split on comma + space, use `split(', ')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can do it without any intermediate variables whatsoever:

```
r = Rectangle(*map(float, input('enter stuff').split(',')))
```

Or if you prefer,

```
r = Rectangle(*[float(x) for x in input('enter stuff').split(',')])
```

This uses the * operator (aka splat operator) to [unpack the argument list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) into your `Rectangle` object.

Comment: I think you meant to put a space after the comma in `split`.

Comment: The `float()` will handle the space.

Comment: @Christian Well, I have learnt something today. I always thought that a float conversion would return an error if it contained whitespace.

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 That takes the list elements, and separates them into positional arguments to be sent to a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can a split by comma `","`:

```
x1, y1, width1, height1 = input("Enter x1, y1, width1, height1: ").split(",")
```

Comment: It still needs to be `map(float`ed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Python 3:

```
try: 
    x, y, w, h = map(float, input("Enter x1, y1, width1, height1: ").split(',')[:4])
    rect = Rectangle2D(x, y, w, h)
except ValueError:
    print "Wrong values"
```