# How do I make my input be in one line (python)

Tags: python

instead of it being

```
7
3
2
```

How do I make it

```
7,3,2
```

This is not my output, just my input

Comment: sry.. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641720/unpack-multiple-floats-from-input and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378091/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python

Comment: Not to sound rough, but that question has already been answered multiple times on the forum, it is better to exhaust research possibilities before asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```py
# 1 input request
res = input()

# split into a numbers array
numbers = res.split(',')

# remove any whitespace next to the numbers
numbers = [number.strip() for number in numbers]
```

These all use built in python functions, which are documented very well in the official python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = input("enter numbers")
#takes in the input

numbers = numbers.split(",")
#splits the input into a list of the values
```